# How to integrate mongoDb in nextjs 13 application (using app router)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

How to use mongodb in next js 13 application, i am using `app` file directory configuration. How to use mongodb community server in nextjs application.

I tried creating folder `services` with mongoose connecting to mongoDB. But couldn't find way to connect mongoDB to nextjs application.
This is my folder structure.

[image]

This is my codebase - https://github.com/its-kunal/Next-Todo

I want to create simple todo application created using MongoDB, NextJs 13.

Comment: What do you mean by "could find anything", while creating the `services` folder?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to connect to database in with mongoose in Next.js

in your project folder create a folder and call it lib or anything

inside lib create a file dbConnect.js

```
//dbConnect.js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const MONGODB_URI = process.env.DB_URL

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);

if (!MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error(
    'Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local'
  )
}

/**
 * Global is used here to maintain a cached connection across hot reloads
 * in development. This prevents connections growing exponentially
 * during API Route usage.
 */
let cached = global.mongoose

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null }
}

async function dbConnect() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      bufferCommands: false,
    }

    cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then((mongoose) => {
      return mongoose
    })
  }

  try {
    cached.conn = await cached.promise
  } catch (e) {
    cached.promise = null
    throw e
  }

  return cached.conn
}

export default dbConnect
```

make sure to to define DB_URL in you .env file

```
//.env
DB_URL=/* your mongodb url */
```

now in your api routes you just have to import the dbconnect funtion

```
import dbConnect from "../../lib/dbConnect";

export default async function handler(req, res) {

    await dbConnect()

     //the rest of your code here

}
```